# Python program to read a file and write the alternate lines into a list/array

Tags: python

I've a requirement to read the alternate lines from a text file and write the output to two lists (odd_list, even_list) where the even lines from the text file should go to even_list and odd lines goes odd_list.

```
sample.txt
aaa
1
bbb
2
ccc
3
ddd
4
```

even_list[] should contain
1,2,3,4
odd_list[] should contain
aaa,bbb,ccc,ddd

As I'm new to python, Can someone help me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it. Please read [How to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
even_list = []
odd_list = []
with open(filename) as infile:
    for index, line in enumerate(infile):
        if index % 2 != 0:
            even_list.append(line.strip())    #even_list.append(int(line.strip()))
        else:
            odd_list.append(line.strip())
print( even_list )
print( odd_list )
```

**Output:**

```
['1', '2', '3', '4']
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
lists = [[],[]]
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(f):
        lists[i%2].append(line)
```

should work.

`lists` is a list of two lists: `lists[0]` is your "even list" while `lists[1]` is your "odd list".